# UWP app with "normal" design and Fluent Design System

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml, fluent-design

I have an UWP app (published in Windows Store), and my app have the "normal" desing, I like update my app for Fluent Design System.
But I would like to add an option in the settings of my app so the user can choose whether he wanted the Fluent Design System (acrylic and transparent effect) or the normal/traditional design.
It is possible? If so how do I do it?
I've tried searching for a solution and I can not find anything

Comment: 1) Themes 2) A Boolean flag in the user config that tells your app whether or not to light up the Fluent Design features 3) A combination of both. You will, of course, have to implement the logic yourself if you add a flag, on top of adding the switch to your app settings.

Comment: App themes are the way to go about it. Create two themes, in the app resource dictionary and just switch.

Answer (score 0):

As BoltClock & iam.Carrot's said, I just made a simple code sample for your reference. You could use a flag to switch between the "normal" and "Fluent" design.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="MyAcrylicBrush"
        BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
        TintColor="#FFFF0000"
        TintOpacity="0.8"
        FallbackColor="#FF7F0000"/>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="default"
        Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

```cs
if (flag) //e.g, true -- acrylic
{
    grid.Background = Application.Current.Resources["MyAcrylicBrush"] as Brush;
}
else
{
    grid.Background = Application.Current.Resources["default"] as Brush;
}
```